# why setAnimationDuration No effect，my Animation is too fast

Tags: objective-c

The method setAnimationDuration has No effect on my code，My Animation is too fast. Here is the code

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];      
image1.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 0,image1.frame.size.height);
image2.frame=CGRectMake(image2.frame.size.width, 0, 0,image2.frame.size.height);
[UIView setAnimationDuration:10];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set your duration value before you change the animatable properties.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:10];
image1.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 0,image1.frame.size.height);
image2.frame=CGRectMake(image2.frame.size.width, 0, 0,image2.frame.size.height);
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

The discussion within Apples class reference for UIView states for the method setAnimationDuration:

> And you must call this method prior to changing the animatable properties of your views. The default value is 0.2 seconds.

That's why you are getting the very fast animations.

This style of animation has been discouraged from ios4, so if the above doesn't work try using the new animation blocks style.

Comment: thanks ,as you say ,now it work

Answer (score 0):

Add animation to your view using:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^()
 {
     //Your code here
 }];
```

Or use this approach:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:super.view duration:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp animations:^
     {
         //your code here
     }completion:NULL
    ];
```